android jetpack compose, why the NavHost resulting in multiple navigations?
Here is a simplified sample which has ScreenNavHost contains NavHost with two route destination composable("userList") and composable("editLogin").
In  UserListForm it has a button when clicking it will navController.navigate("editLogin") to open the EditLoginForm, and in EditLoginForm its button click will navController.popBackStack() to back to UserListForm.
But the log shows a few round of navigations, which are not expected (?).
Here is the log:

app start, it shows the UserListForm:

 +++ enter AppContent
 +++ --- exit AppContent
 +++ enter ScreenNavHost
 +++  ScreenNavHost.NavHost.composable("userList") 
 +++ enter UserListForm
 +++ --- exit ScreenNavHost


clicking the button on the UserListForm to navController.navigate("editLogin"), the EditLoginForm is eventually shown.

 +++ in UserListForm.Button.onClick{}, call navController.navigate("editLogin")
 +++  ScreenNavHost.NavHost.composable("userList") 
 +++ enter UserListForm
 +++  ScreenNavHost.NavHost.composable("editLogin") 
 +++ enter EditLoginForm
 +++  ScreenNavHost.NavHost.composable("userList")
 +++ enter UserListForm
 +++  ScreenNavHost.NavHost.composable("editLogin") 
 +++ enter EditLoginForm
 +++  ScreenNavHost.NavHost.composable("editLogin") 
 +++ enter EditLoginForm 


Clicking on the button on the EditLoginForm to navController.popBackStack(). It eventually show the UserListForm, but also navigate to the destination route  "editLogin" and "userList" a few times.

 +++ in EditLoginForm.Button.onClick{}, call navController.popBackStack()
 +++  ScreenNavHost.NavHost.composable("editLogin") 
 +++ enter EditLoginForm
 +++  ScreenNavHost.NavHost.composable("userList") 
 +++ enter UserListForm
 +++  ScreenNavHost.NavHost.composable("editLogin") 
 +++ enter EditLoginForm
 +++  ScreenNavHost.NavHost.composable("userList") 
 +++ enter UserListForm
 +++  ScreenNavHost.NavHost.composable("userList") 
 +++ enter UserListForm

Question, are these redounded navigation expected?  Or is it caused by the NavHost() not coded correctly?
The code are listed below:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            AppContent()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun AppContent() {
    Log.w("+++", "+++ enter AppContent")
    MyTestNavApplicationTheme {
        // Create a NavController which is responsible for navigating between composables
        val navController = rememberNavController()

        Scaffold() { innerPadding ->
            ScreenNavHost(
                navController = navController,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
            )
        }
    }
    Log.w("+++", "+++ --- exit AppContent")
}

@Composable
fun ScreenNavHost(
    navController: NavHostController,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Log.i("+++", "+++ enter ScreenNavHost")
    Box(modifier=Modifier.border(width=0.dp, color= Color(0xFF004940))) {
        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "userList", modifier = modifier) {
            // Define the composable for the "userList" route
            composable("userList") {

                Log.i("+++", "+++  ScreenNavHost.NavHost.composable(\"userList\") ")
                // open UserListForm
                UserListForm(navController)
            }

            composable("editLogin") {

                Log.i("+++", "+++  ScreenNavHost.NavHost.composable(\"editLogin\") ")
                // open EditLoginForm
                EditLoginForm(navController)

            }
        }
    }
    Log.i("+++", "+++ --- exit ScreenNavHost")
}

@Composable
fun UserListForm(navController: NavHostController) {
    Log.d("+++", "+++ enter UserListForm")
    Button(
        onClick = {
            Log.d("+++", "+++ in UserListForm.Button.onClick{}, call navController.navigate(\"editLogin\")")
            navController.navigate("editLogin")
        }
    ) {
        Text("back -->")
    }
}

@Composable
fun EditLoginForm(navController: NavHostController) {
    Log.d("+++", "+++ enter EditLoginForm")
    Button(
        onClick = {
            Log.d("+++", "+++ in EditLoginForm.Button.onClick{}, call navController.popBackStack()")
            navController.popBackStack()
        }
    ) {
        Text("back -->")
    }
}


This is a frequently discussed topic without a definitive answer so far, at least to my knowledge. What we know is that this is related to the animation that is happening during navigation.
It seems there are two things coming into play here:

enterTransition and exitTransition of the Composables
the default Crossfade animation that Jetpack Compose uses

You can explicitly specify that you don't want any animation when entering / exiting a Composable like this:
composable(route = "userList", enterTransition = { EnterTransition.None }, exitTransition = { ExitTransition.None }) {
    //...
}

composable(route = "editLogin", enterTransition = { EnterTransition.None }, exitTransition = { ExitTransition.None }) {
    //..
}

You then can observe that the number of recompositions is reduced down to this:
D  +++ in UserListForm.Button.onClick{}, call navController.navigate("editLogin")
I  +++  ScreenNavHost.NavHost.composable("userList") 
D  +++ enter UserListForm
I  +++  ScreenNavHost.NavHost.composable("editLogin") 
D  +++ enter EditLoginForm
I  +++  ScreenNavHost.NavHost.composable("editLogin") 
D  +++ enter EditLoginForm
I  +++  ScreenNavHost.NavHost.composable("editLogin") 
D  +++ enter EditLoginForm

The phenomenon that the target destination is recomposed multiple times was reported on the Google Issue Tracker, and also happens in Google Sample Apps.
